# How to set up a Tor relay in Ubuntu?

Tags: tor

I am trying to set up a relay in Ubuntu. I am able to install Tor and run it but when I go to edit the file I end up never being able to connect.

Is there a step by step guide for setting one up besides the one that is on the main Tor site? I have the port forwarded on my router and firewall already.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the Tor file name is you're trying to edit?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 3):

The [Tor Project](https://torproject.org/) maintains a site which explains [how to set up a relay](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/). Usually all you need is to edit the `torrc` file. The file resides in `/etc/tor/torrc` when you install it via package management.

You need to set `ORPort` and `ExitPolicy`:

```
ORPort 9001
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

The network uses the `ORPort` to contact your Tor relay and the `ExitPolicy` above advises to be a middle router (reject all exit connections).

Save the settings and restart the Tor process:

```
sudo service tor restart
```

Now look at the log file in `/var/log/tor/`. When it shows the following line, all is good:

> Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent.

If not you might want to do some research at [Tor's Q&A page](https://tor.stackexchange.com/). Furthermore the following site might be interesting: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tips-running-exit-node-minimal-harassment

Comment: The “https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en” link is no more since 2019. A replacement (presumedly up-to-date) is at https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who is looking for the easiest way to set up their own Tor relay I made this config generator: https://tor-relay.co/

You just have to enter some basic information for your configuration and the app generates a custom install script that will install Tor and its dependencies on your system.

It provides you with a single command like the one below that you just have to run on your server,

```
curl https://tor-relay.co/nf/188b44[...]9dc162.sh | bash
```

The only knowledge you need to have is how to log in to your server via ssh.

Comment: You should copy the relevant steps from your site into here.  You can always refer to your site at the bottom of your post as a reference for your answer though...